# Where to find Atmospheric data for various cities

Tags: organic-chemistry, reference-request

Hi im searching for atmospheric data on the following:

```
Air quality, Dust Particle Concentration, Pollution, Average Temperature etc
```

for various cities such as Frankfurt, London, Hong Kong, Bangkok...

Are there any websites that can give me this data (or similar atmospheric measurements) for each city?

Comment: I'm not sure if any single resource exists for these data, but [NASA maintains a list](http://gcmd.gsfc.nasa.gov/learn/pointers/meteo.html) of websites that host atmospheric and climate data.

Comment: this would be more on topic on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36296/geoscience - no sugestion to close, but support Geoscience SE!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about chemistry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most cities used to have own pages about pollution data. But there are other sources. For example:

London: http://www.londonair.org.uk/LondonAir/Default.aspx

Bangkok: http://www.pcd.go.th/airquality/bangkok/

If you are looking for a single page, try this:

http://aqicn.org/city/all/